# Which x86 ISA extensions imply support for previous SIMD extensions?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, avx, cpuid

My CPU supports the following technologies: MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, and AVX.

When I write my code and check for hardware support, can I assume things like "If the processor supports AVX, it ALWAYS supports all of these other technologies"?

Which of these technologies are considered super-sets of the others and which ones are stand-alone and not necessarily packaged with the other ones?

Comment: Yes, AVX requires support for all of Intel's previous SSE instructions, but maybe not necessarily AES or PCLMUL, IIRC.  And SSE1 implies MMX.  I think there's a duplicate of this, looking now.

Comment: Are you interested only in SIMD, or also in extensions like BMI2 and popcnt?  (`popcnt` is technically separate from SSE4.2).

Comment: Yeah, I saw the duplicate in the related thing AFTER I made the post. I appreciate the help anyway.